# Java: Use URL as Path object

Tags: java, file, url, path

I am using some code from a different program. I don't fully understand how it works, but I know how I can use it. The program uses a text file from your pc, but the text file I want to use is not a file I have downloaded. It's 'an online file' as a link that starts with `https://`, that I want to use. For the program to work, it needs the file to be a Path object, but I can't figure out, how to make the URL into a Path, without the program stopping and giving an error. I have tried using the `[url].toURI()`. Didn't work. I have tried different methods of making the URL, but I couldn't find a method, that works.

It would make most sense for the program to not download the file, but it is a possibility, if it's not possible to make the other thing work (I already tried, and I also had problems with that. Most methods I could find didn't work, because some lines got mixed, which makes it not work with the program).

**Edit:** As I expected, it's not possible to do, so I need to find out how I can download the text file, as the exact same file. The lines needs to stay the same, something can't be moved to a different line.

Comment: You can't convert a URL into a Path, because a Path is a representation of an object *on a locally mounted filesystem*.

Comment: I would use something like `Files.copy(url.openStream(), Files.createTempFile());` but you will need to close (and maybe buffer) the stream and save the `Path` object to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

First of, as I said in the edit, it's not possible to use URL directly as a path. As a workaround, I made a temporary file, which [this](https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-temporary-filesfolders-in-java) website helped me with.

After that, I needed to print the text file from the URL to the temporary file. I used the NIO method from [here](https://www.journaldev.com/924/java-download-file-url).

I hope this can help, if others have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url=getClass().getResource("https://websiteYouTryToDownloadTheFileFrom/yourfile.txt"); 
File yourFile=new File(url.toURI());
```